# How can I use sharp on AWS Lambda with pnpm?

Tags: sharp, pnpm

I'm trying to run a lambda function with `sharp` installed. Sharp has instructions to [install on AWS Lambda](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#aws-lambda), but they are specific to `npm`. Specifically it requires me to run this:

```
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --libc=glibc sharp
```

`pnpm` doesn't explicitly [support the arch and platform options](https://pnpm.io/cli/install) however.

I'm developing on a Max but am using [Seed.run](https://seed.run/) for CI/CD.

So far I really like pnpm and seed and I don't want to change either one. Is there a way for pnpm to install the right library?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass unknown options to pnpm by prefixing them with config:

```
pnpm install --config.arch=x64 --config.platform=linux --config.libc=glibc sharp
```